Why doesn't "I never found the right one" use the present perfect?
In the movie "Find me falling" (see clip)

The man: Why aren't you married?
The woman: Why aren't you married?
The man: I never found the right one.
The woman: I didn't either.

As I see, not finding the right one is still right in the present. why didn't the actor use the present perfect?

The man: I've never found the right one.
The woman: I haven't either.

Is that in the US, for something still true in the present, we can use the simple past instead of present perfect.

This is not just American English. It's just English. Learners should try and realize that most differences are terms, like lift and elevator and not things like. He never found the right one at some point in the past.

@Lambie there is a grammatical difference between American and British English with respect to use of the perfect, though, this question just isn't one of them.

@hunter That is mostly a myth...

Another point I don't see addressed yet: Most people who marry do so by the time they're 30, much earlier until recently. These actors look about 40, and we're meant to understand that they're no longer actively looking for romance because they expected to find it when they were younger. (And eventually decided it wasn't worth the effort, etc.…)
Therefore, they "never found" anyone when they were searching, which doesn't continue through the present.

The difference is in whether they've given up or are still looking. As you said, they appear to no longer expect to find "the right one".

An good argument. I would expect someone in their twenties use a phrase like "I've not yet found the right one."

Actually you have it backwards.  Not being married is the present state. That they never found the right one is the prior thing that explains the present state.
Never found is like never met, not an ongoing state but a (negated) discrete event.

what is the difference between using the present perfect and the simple past in this context?

We frame experience with language, casting it in a certain light.  The experience remains the same but the presentation of the experience is what changes. To say "I have never found" suggests that the search has continued until now, or at least until recently, whereas to say "I never found" suggests that the speaker may have stopped looking for the right one., or at the very least the speaker is consigning the search, so far, to the past.

@TimR what does "consign to the past" in your latest comment mean?

@justhalf  consign is used figuratively there. To leave behind the disappointed searching for the right one.  To concern themselves no longer about that searching. Either to give up searching and accept that there is no right one, or perhaps now they feel they have indeed met the right one.  Whatever the reason, they are leaving those earlier searches behind.

Unconvincing. "I've never met him" would be proper, wouldn't it? "I never met him", by contrast, would for example be used for someone who is now dead.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica  The present perfect is a way to express the situation, but not the way, as the simple past is also valid and has its own nuances.  "The right one" does not refer to a particular existing identifiable individual, and so your point about using the past when the person is dead doesn't apply here. That's an entirely different context.


I haven't seen the movie, but often in movies when two people discuss their love lives, it's because they are the "right ones" for each other. If this is the case, and they know it, or even just suspect it or want to leave the possibility open, then they have a good reason not to use the perfect: They are unmarried, but maybe "not finding the right one" is not true in the present.
But setting that aside: The situation is a bit different with a negative statement. If someone did something consistently in the past, and continues to in the present, they're pretty much forced to use the perfect tense: "I've driven a cab for years." But for statements about something that didn't happen, we have more option to use simple past: "This ice cream is delicious! I never had ice cream before!" Or "Hey, you're from Ireland! I never met an Irishman I didn't like!" Presumably the speaker doesn't intend an insult; presumably they are still "not meeting" an Irishman whom they dislike. In these cases, we do also have the option of using present perfect, but past simple is not off the table.


I feel like the example in the question and your last two bolded examples are just sloppy colloquial speech.  It's common, but I would say not technically correct.
